# Why is my printf() not printing the first character in the text file?

Tags: c, file, error-handling, file-handling

I am a noob C programmer.
I can't read all the characters of my text file.
My file.txt has numbers: 9,2,3,4,5,6 but when I run the code written below, it just skips 9 and prints the rest of the numbers. However, when I put a space before 9, it runs perfectly. How do I fix it? and why does it happen?

```
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
int a[10];
char ch;

while((ch=getc(fp))!= EOF)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[ch]);
    printf("%d ", a[ch]);
}
```

Thanks in advance;

Comment: `a[10]` is too small to be indexed by an ascii character! You place it outside your memory: undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, `getc` gets a character, in your case the first `9`, then reads the `2` with `fscanf`, then reads the `3` with `getc`, then....etc.

Comment: ..and I am not sure what you want to do. It all looks very clumsy.

Comment: Note that `getc()` returns an `int` value, and a `char` may not be able to hold `EOF`, so `char ch;` --> `int ch;`.

Answer (score 2):

Function `getc` in `while((ch=getc(fp))!= EOF)` consumes a single character from the file; if `9` is the first character in your file, it will simply be read into `ch` and - as your character set is likely to be ASCII - will set `ch==0x39`.

So (1) the `9` will then not be available any more for `fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[ch]);`; that's why you think it is "skipped".

(2) writing to `a` at position `ch` then exceeds the array bounds of `a`.

Comment: Then, what should I do to read or scan all the integers from a file efficiently?

Comment: @Xedron Can you explain why you are using `ch` as an index of your a[] array? and what does you input file look like. It's difficult to help because your code is not just reading integers from a file.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear how many `int`'s you have in your file and the current way of storing them is error prone. `fgetc` returns an `int` that is either `EOF` (-1) or 0-255, so `ch` should have been declared `int` and then when `(ch=getc(fp))!= EOF` is true, `ch` will contain 0-255.
In the following `fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[ch]);` you are again reading from the file, but into the array at the index position `ch`, which is clearly not your intention (and it will also probably crash when you read a character with value > 9. Hint: a '0' has value 48). The below solution may seem overly complicated, but I'm used to C++ where this stuff happens under the hood and you don't have to bother about it much. Perhaps you'll get some ideas by depickling it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* dynamic memory storage - start */
typedef struct {
    size_t m_size;
    size_t m_reserved;
    int* m_data;
} store;

/* create a store */
store* store_create() {
    store* s = malloc(sizeof(store));
    if(s) {
        /* initialize values */
        s->m_size = 0;
        s->m_reserved = 1; /* a very conservative start value */
        s->m_data = malloc(sizeof(int)*s->m_reserved);
        if(s->m_data==NULL) {
            free(s);
            s = NULL;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

/* destroy a store */
void store_destroy(store* s) {
    /* free the integer array */
    free(s->m_data);
    /* free the store struct */
    free(s);
}

bool store_reserve(store* s, size_t new_res) {
    /* reserve more space for the int's if needed */
    if(new_res>s->m_reserved) {
        int* n = realloc(s->m_data, sizeof(int)*new_res);
        if(n==NULL) return false; /* could not expand storage */
        s->m_reserved = new_res;
        s->m_data = n;
    }
    return true;
}

// check if it's time to increase reserved storage
bool store_check_reserve(store* s) {
    if(s->m_size == s->m_reserved)
        /* change 5/4 to a larger value for more aggressive
         * increase of memory allocation */
        return store_reserve(s, (s->m_reserved+1)*5/4);
    else
        return true;
}

// add a value to the store
bool store_add(store* s, int v) {
    if(!store_check_reserve(s)) return false;

    s->m_data[s->m_size++] = v;
    return true;
}

/* dynamic memory storage - end */

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    /* create a store for our unknown amount of int's */
    store* myStore = store_create();

    /* scan for strings separated by comma and newline
     * and allocate memory for it */
    char* str;
    while(fscanf(fp, " %m[^,\n],", &str)==1)
    {
        int num;
        /* convert string to integer */
        if(sscanf(str, "%d", &num)==1) {
            /* store the extracted value */
            if(store_add(myStore, num)==false) {
                fprintf(stderr, "FAILED STORING %d\n", num);
            }
        }
        // free string allocated by fscanf (%m) */
        free(str);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("All %d stored values:\n", myStore->m_size);
    for(size_t i=0; i<myStore->m_size; ++i) {
        printf("%d = %d\n", i, myStore->m_data[i]);
    }

    /* release memory allocated by our store */
    store_destroy(myStore);
    return 0;
}
```